# Apsalar & Facebook SDK - Both need return statements in application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation

Tags: ios

**Apsalar Asks:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
 [Apsalar startSession:@"yourAPIKey" withKey:@"yourSecret" andURL:url]; 
 return YES;
}
```

http://support.apsalar.com/customer/portal/articles/717510-integrating-the-ios-sdk

**Facebook Asks**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

I'm not sure which one to use, as I assume the first return statement "finishes" the method call, so anything after that won't get called.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to safely use both. It depends on whether they'll safely ignore the URLs that the other one is supposed to handle. It might be worth contacting the support teams for both pieces of software to determine what each one will do when it's given a URL that wasn't intended for it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
[Apsalar startSession:@"yourAPIKey" withKey:@"yourSecret" andURL:url];
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```